# Best Data structure to be used for parsing arithmetic expressions

Tags: c++, parsing, data-structures

Suppose that we are going to write a computer code for a parser that parses arithmetic expressions, in simple terms, a program that inspects arithmetic expression for validity. For example, given an arithmetic expression (a / ( b + c) ) x d we would like to see if the parenthesis are matching properly. Which data structure would be the best that can be used to match correct parenthesis in the expression.

Comment: If you only need to check the number of paranthesis, not a complete parser, you could just use a `std::stack`. Push a `(` when you find it, pop it when a `)` is read. If you try to pop an empty stack or if the stack is not empty at the end, the expression is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The output of most parsers is either a *parse tree* showing how the string is structured or an *abstract syntax tree* showing the semantic meaning of the input string. In your case, if you’re looking for something to the effect of “what parenthesis matches this other one,” you’d probably want a parse tree. You could then match the parenthesis with its soul mate by finding which parse tree node has it as a child.